# file code formatting lost when upload to server

Tags: php, code-formatting

I am using NetBeans

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java: 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_11-b12
```

when i deploy file to the server it lost code formatting. Lets take a following snapshot of file, it has all code formatting, indents spaces etc

[image: this is before uploading to server]

but when i upload it to server it lost all code formatting

[image: after uploaded to server]

**it happens to php and js files** , this change cause problems for me

---

When i open this file using dreamweaver and simply save and upload the file remains the same, it only happens in NetBeans, but don't know why, i deeply read the code formatting setting in NetBeans but nothing helped me

Comment: It looks like you're losing your newlines. Are you going between systems? Linux/Unix have different newlines characters to Windows etc.

Comment: It is minifying the code, check if there is some setting to turn this off.

Comment: @Vkas it's just not displaying new line characters, all other whitespace and variable names etc. are preserved.

Comment: @Jonathon Yes probably it lost new lines, i am from Windows to Linux

Comment: @Vkas When i open this file using dreamweaver and simply save and upload the file remains the same, it only happens in NetBeans, but don't know why, i deeply read the code formatting setting in NetBeans but nothing helped me

Comment: What are you using to upload files? You should ensure that ASCII mode is enabled for text files (Or it could be possibly binary mode, give both a shot) and try uploading/downloading again. This should hopefully preserve line breaks/feeds.

Comment: @Jonathon i am using CuteFTP 8.0.5 for file uploading and how i ensure that ASCII mode is enabled for files in CuteFTP 8.0.5, but one thing i want to share which i didnt (sorry for that), when i open the same file in Dreamweaver, save and upload then it doesn't happen, it only happens in netbeans

Comment: You should probably just check your settings in both programs for line endings. I don't have either software installed so I can't confirm, but find out what the difference is between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Vkas and @Jonathon to drag my attention to the problem, i was unable to understand the problem, and the problem was line ending format, thanks once again @Jonathon!

Actually NetBeans editor respects the line separator used in an existing file. It reads the file into an editor document instance in the following way:
First line of the file is read and the line separator type is determined - it is expected to be one of

- "\n" (LF)- Unix
- "\r" (CR)- Mac
- "\r\n" (CRLF) - Windows

The line separator type is remembered in the document instance for future save operation.
All the lines in the file are read and their line separator (regardless of what type it is) is translated to "\n" that is the only line separator type that the editor is able to work with.

Upon save operation each "\n" in the document is translated into the remembered line separator type.

Note: If there would be a mixture of line separators of multiple types throughout the file then only the line separator type from the original first line will be used upon save.
For new files (constructed from templates) the editor uses platform-default line separator.

**Currently there are no additional options for handling line separators.**

At last a tiny little plugin for NetBeans helped me ([can be found here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46829/change-line-endings-on-save)), this plugin helps you to give options of line ending format under Tools > Editor with new tab **Line Endings**. You can also install this plugin from Tools > Plugins

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the project level end line format by right clicking on project Properties > Line Endings